# Replace one Column in a Multidimensional Array in a For Loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Current state:

1 Multi Array np.ndarray (2000 Rows and 7 Columns)

Then I have a function (for loop) which only looks at one (2000 Rows and 1 Column) at a time -> So the For Loop is going to run 7 Times

The Calculations will be stored in another array called out (2000 Rows and 1 Column)

Problem:

I want to store the Result in the same Multi Array as I started with

Question:

Is there a Replace Function in Numpy or any other Method to Replace it

Comment: please be specific, provide a meaningful reproducible example (input+output)

Comment: @mozway done. the input is irrelevant, and the output also the format need to be right.

Comment: I think you just made the question worse… please read [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array slicing to access subarrays of a `np.ndarray`:

```
# Assuming 'Row-Major' storage
column = arr[:,columnIdx]

# Assigning an array of zeros to column
arr[:,columnIdx] = np.zeros_like(column)
```

Edit: Here is a working example

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(700).reshape(100,7)

# compute values modulo column ordinal

for columnIdx in range(7):
    column[:,columnIdx] %= columnIdx + 1


print(arr)
```